# jQuery Animated Scrolling: Can I limit the function to specific targets?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm new to jQuery (bear with me) and am using a snippet courtesy of css-tricks, to enable animated scrolling to targets on a single page site, from the navigation menu.

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Currently, it seems to apply to any use of an a href="#" on the page, rather than just to the sections targeted in the nav.

The nav html is as follows:

```
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li id="navwhat"><a href="#sectionwhat"><div class="navicon what"><img src="images/ah_nav_what_01.png" alt="what i do" name="navwhaticon" id="navwhaticon"></div><span>what i do</span></a></li>
            <li id="navwork"><a href="#sectionwork"><div class="navicon work"><img src="images/ah_nav_work_01.png" alt="my work" name="navworkicon" id="navworkicon"></div><span>my work</span></a></li>
            <li id="navexperience"><a href="#sectionexperience"><div class="navicon experience"><img src="images/ah_nav_experience_01.png" alt="my experience" name="navexperienceicon" id="navexperienceicon"></div><span>my experience</span></a></li>
            <li id="navabout"><a href="#sectionabout"><div class="navicon about"><img src="images/ah_nav_about_01.png" alt="about me" name="navabouticon" id="navabouticon"></div><span>about me</span></a></li>
            <li id="navcontact"><a href="#sectioncontact"><div class="navicon contact"><img src="images/ah_nav_contact_01.png" alt="contact me" name="navcontacticon" id="navcontacticon"></div><span>contact me</span></a></li>
            <li id="navfind"><a href="#sectionfind"><div class="navicon find"><img src="images/ah_nav_find_01.png" alt="find me" name="navfindicon" id="navfindicon"></div><span>find me</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

How do I limit the function to the nav targets?

Do I specify each section div individually in jQuery?

Do I apply a class to the target sections and specify the class in the function?

Can the function be applied only to links in the nav div?

Any and all advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Many thanks, knew it'd be a schoolboy issue ...

Answer (score 0):

Just add  `nav` to the selector -> `$('nav a[href*=#]:not([href=#])')` to target only anchors inside the nav element

```
$(function () {
    $('nav a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```